# CSS IMG Double border: One needed for spacing and the other for rounded corners

Tags: image, border, css

I have an image and it has a bottom border.

Now, I want to try and give this IMG rounded corners in CSS but I am unable to do so because the radius property affects the first border of course.

Is there any way to do this?

This is my original border which I'm using with the image before the text.

```
div img {            
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;            
}
```

So I need to create rounded corners for an img which already has this border(without changing it). Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Don't use a bottom border as a seperator, place a `div` with a height of 1px and color set to #eee between each image, then round the corners on the image

Comment: why don't you simply use a margin for spacing and use borders for what they are intended?

Comment: @Fabio I meant spacing like a "visual spacing" from text.

Comment: @BadKarma I am using it for "visual spacing", so the image sits on the mentioned border and beneath is text.

Comment: quite probably there's a way to do what you want, but I can't even understand what you're doing, why, and what you're trying to achieve. Maybe some image to show? Sorry but it's not clear

Comment: @Fabio Its perfectly clear. I have an image with a bottom border. I just want to round the corners of the image without needing to remove the bottom border. I don't want to remove that border or mess with it. I just want to round the corners of the image on top of the current setup. Is it more clear now?

Comment: what about using some padding instead border ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iBKao  i still do not really nderstand the purpose/real need of this border/space . image could just be 100% width and not block to keep that space underneath ... you are not clear , but maybe it is because you do not handle CSS good enough yet :) a screen of expected result and html context would help us to understand you.

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks for the the idea but the radius of the border is also rounding the padding because padding is just a part of the image. I just need that border to stay as it is if that's possible. Doesn't matter why. My images have white background and they represent products, beneath the image is text - description and I'm using this border to visually separate the product image from product description...can't explain it any better in this short message.

Comment: so inline-block or margin-bottom do not work ?, have you tried even to increase line-height. that border on image looks to me the last place to go to get some extra spacing beneath an element :)

Comment: @GCyrillus I'm not trying to get extra spacing..I told you I don't need more space..I can't explain it here, I know it sounds dull. Just focus on my question: Is it possible to have a border on an image and round the corners of that image in a way you don't need to change that first border? So I need a straight bottom border and rounded corners, that's all. Your first try with padding was on the right path.